# What does this return

Tags: javascript

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById("past").getElementsByClassName("ball ball-8")[0];
if (targetDiv.length>0) {
        alert("Black roll");
}
else alert("something else");
```

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="past">
<div data-rollid="69106" class="ball ball-8">13</div>
<div data-rollid="69107" class="ball ball-1">7</div>
<div data-rollid="69108" class="ball ball-1">5</div>
<div data-rollid="69109" class="ball ball-8">13</div>
<div data-rollid="69115" class="ball ball-8">8</div></div>
```

The problem is that it never runs the code in the If.
From what I know

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementById("past").getElementsByClassName("ball ball-8")[0];
```

Should return an array right?

Comment: `console.debug(targetDiv)`...!? You get *one element* because you're selecting `[0]`, not an array.

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('#past .ball.ball-8')`

Comment: It would return an array if you omit the index selector at the end.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName(...)` returns an array(-like), but `getElementsByClassName(...)[0]` selected the first element of it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what you're doing here. You're really doing three steps in one.

```
document.getElementById("past").getElementsByClassName("ball ball-8")[0];
```

First, you're getting the Element with the ID `past`. That's obviously going to return a single element.

Next, within that element, you're getting all Elements with the Class names `ball` and `ball-8`. That'll return a list of Elements.

Finally, you're using array syntax to get the 0th element of that array. This means that in the end, you're going to be returning a single Element: the first one returned by the call to `getElementsByClassName`. If you want to return the full list of Elements, then you should remove the `[0]` from the end of the chain.

Comment: The thing I want to do is get the last roll if it was "ball ball-8" , "ball ball-1" or "ball ball-0"

Comment: Well that certainly isn't what this code is doing. You never even mention ball-0 or ball-1 in this code. If you need further help understanding how to do such a thing, you'll want to post a different question that clearly states what you're trying to do and seeks specific help in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

The thing I wanted to do is get the last child of the Div with Id"past" and I found a way to do it.

```
var lastRoll = document.getElementById("past");
var lastChild = past.lastChild.innerHTML;
```

My approach to the problem before was a really bad one.